# springfox - Swagger2Controller: Unable to find specification for group default

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

Don't work /v2/api-docs return **404**

At this time in Logs - **Swagger2Controller: Unable to find specification for group default**

Beans Docker creating ok in spring...
But Swagger2Controller.DocumentationCache is empty...

Help my please.....

Before, it's was work....

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    fun allApi(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
    }
}
```

gradle:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot')

// Rest
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')

// Web
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

// Security
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-config')

// Jackson
compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')

//     Vaadin
compile('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')

// DB
runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')

// Kotlin
compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

// Sentry
compile 'io.sentry:sentry:1.7.2'
compile 'com.getsentry.raven:raven-logback:8.0.3'

// Log to json
compile('ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5')
compile "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:5.0"
// Logs {IF}
compile "org.codehaus.janino:janino"

// Swagger
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2"
```

Comment: Avoid adding "Resolved" or similar titles to your *question*. If an answer below answers this question, mark it as accepted by hitting the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget on it..... ))))

springfox.documentation.auto-startup: **true**